# Create an EventSubscriber for a specific module

Tags: 8, event-subscribers

I'm attempting to make something occur at a specific event in the GatherContent module found here https://www.drupal.org/project/gathercontent

Based on the information here http://help.gathercontent.com/importing-and-exporting-content/drupal-integration/drupal-integration-extending-the-module-using-the-api and several tutorials and documentation

I created a module with the code entered like so

my_gathercontent.services.yml

```
services:
  my_gathercontent:
    class: '\Drupal\my_gathercontent\EventSubscriber\MyGatherContentSubscriber'
    tags:
      - { name: 'event_subscriber' }
```

src/EventSubscriber/MyGatherContentSubscriber.php

```
namespace Drupal\my_gathercontent\EventSubscriber;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

/**
 * Event Subscriber MyGatherContentSubscriber.
 */

class MyGatherContentSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface {
    public function onGatherContentPostImport(DrupalgathercontentEventPostImportEvent $event) {
        \Drupal::logger('my_gathercontent')->notice('This is a test');
        drupal_set_message("Debug: This is a test.");
        var_dump($event);
    }
    public static function getSubscribedEvents() {
        $events['gathercontent.post_import'] = ['onGatherContentPostImport'];
        return $events;
    }
}
```

And none of those messages get logged. I do now receive a page not found message after performing an action that should trigger that event. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Is there something wrong with the way I'm attempting to subscribe to the event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each event in the `$events` array should itself be an array; try:

```
$events['gathercontent.post_import'][] = ['onGatherContentPostImport'];
```